# Figuring out a Type Synonym's Type

Tags: haskell

I made a type synonym in Haskell:

```
Prelude> type Foo a = [a]
```

Then, I checked its type:

```
Prelude> :t [5] :: Foo Integer
[5] :: Foo Integer :: Foo Integer
```

Of course I know that `Foo a` is a type synonym for `[a]` since I just wrote it.

But, if I were consuming a library that returned `Foo Integer`, how would I know what `Foo` is?

I tried `:t Foo` without success.

Comment: Use `:kind!` to evaluate type-level expressions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Try this: `:i Foo`

`:i` gives information about a bound symbol.
`:t` gives type signature for expressions. (which is why it didn't work for you - `Foo` is not an expression, like a function or a value is).

Example:

```
ghci> :i String
type String = [Char]    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
```

---

And here's bonus information:

`:i` is also awesome for ADTs, it will give you the constructors + tell you which instances they derive (from the imported modules, of course). For example:

```
ghci> :i Bool
data Bool = False | True    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Types’
instance Bounded Bool -- Defined in ‘GHC.Enum’
instance Enum Bool -- Defined in ‘GHC.Enum’
instance Eq Bool -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
instance Ord Bool -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
instance Read Bool -- Defined in ‘GHC.Read’
instance Show Bool -- Defined in ‘GHC.Show’
```

And it's also awesome for type-classes, for example:

```
ghci> :i Monad
class Monad (m :: * -> *) where
  (>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b
  (>>) :: m a -> m b -> m b
  return :: a -> m a
  fail :: String -> m a
    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Monad Maybe -- Defined in ‘Data.Maybe’
instance Monad (Either e) -- Defined in ‘Data.Either’
instance Monad [] -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Monad IO -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
instance Monad ((->) r) -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
```

And, as mentioned, can also be used for functions:

```
ghci> :i id
id :: a -> a    -- Defined in ‘GHC.Base’
```

It is almost exactly like `:t`, only that it will also tell you in what module the symbol is defined.

So why use `:t`? it's more flexible. `:i` only works for bound symbols. E.g. `:t (+5)` is valid. `:i (+5)` is not.

Comment: a *thorough* answer! :)